# How to remove "python.exe" from open with list after it is uninstalled?

Tags: python, windows, regedit

I was reinstalling python, but after I uninstall python, python.exe was showing as an option in the open with list of windows 11 even though it was not installed. I reinstalled python but when i tried to add the new python.exe as default, it didn't work and it was showing the old python which wasn't even installed.

I tried to remove it from the open with list but i couldn't

Comment: What do you mean by "open with list"?

Comment: @HoangMinhQuangFX15045 If you right click a file, then click "Open with...", there is a list of programs. It seems that it has something to do with registry https://www.thewindowsclub.com/remove-unwanted-programs-recommended-programs-list-open-with-box

Comment: I don't know where is the error. But in the "Open with.." window, you could point to your new install python.exe file location, also tick on "Always using this app to open this file's type" to make sure.

Comment: i tried to do the same thing, but it didn't work

Comment: You can either edit the registry `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\(.ext)\OpenWithList` (but be aware that you can break your system if you change things you should not change) or use a tool. Search for "OpenWith" on this page [Nirsoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/) (did not test the tool, but I know other tools from nirsoft and was very happy with them)

Comment: this method I also tried this, but the problem is that even though python is not installed. the option is in the list but the registry editor doesn't show the python.exe option. OpenWithView has the same problem